# an integer changed itself for no reason, could it be for memory issues?

Tags: c, variables, int

I have a long program that has an int max in it. It wasn't working and i found out that max changed itself to 0 for no reason since after its first value is never changed.

I used a lot of prints to find out where it happens and for some reason happens here:

```
printf("max is: %d\n",max); 
qtail->block=0;
printf("max is: %d\n",max);
```

Before this instruction, max has its correct value, and after it max is 0. How?? That pointer has absolutely nothing to do with max, maybe I ran out of stack memory and the program started rewriting itself?...block is an int too but inside a struct

Comment: You most likely invoke *undefined behavior*, but we'll need a proper [mcve] to tell you where (most likely `qtail` isn't initialized or a null pointer)

Comment: *"maybe I ran out of stack memory and the program started rewriting itself?"* - Not on any modern OS.

Comment: Wow...that sounds like magic, an int that changes itself!

Comment: Seems that `qtail->block` is the same address as `max`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Or it partially overlaps `max` so that zeroing it out zeroes all the non-zero parts of `max`.

Comment: Try `printf("%p : %p", &(qtail->block), &max);` to see if they possibly point to the same address.

Comment: Just a kudo for ferociously debugging until you narrowed it down to three lines. Very well done!

Comment: thanks everyone, it was the same address problem indeed, but I'm not very experienced so it didn't come to my mind

Comment: Well, now you should investigate *why* it was the same address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happened because of undefined behaviour; by using

```
 printf("%p : %p", &(qtail->block), &max);
```

I saw that max and the qtail pointer had the same address and corrected what caused it.

Comment: If `qtail->block` has type `int` and `&qtail->block == &max` then the behavior you observed is perfectly well defined, and exactly what one would expect.  There may be some UB responsible for those two pointers being aliased, but you left that out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Nitpick: arguments matching a `"%p"` specifier in printf should be of type `(void*)`, with a cast if needed.

Comment: No cast is ever needed when passing any pointer type argument to a function that takes void *.

Comment: just wander, what was the reason for getting different vars allocated at the same address in your case? can you update the answer with explanation?

Comment: @ LeeDanielCrocker `printf` does not have a `void*` argument. Pointers to different types are not necessarily the same size, so the `(void*)` cast is precautionary, for the `%p` specifier to be given the correct value.